# Vagrant/Puppet --- ensure: change from present failed: Could not set 'present on ensure: No such file or dir

Tags: php, apache, apc, puppet, vagrant

I am using Vagrant and Puppet to install Apache and PHP on Ubuntu. However I am getting the error below during `vagrant up`. I think the path for the templates are correct, then why the error?

*I'm using the setup [here](https://github.com/danackerson/awo-puppet) modified to ensure `apt-get update` runs before anything else*

**Error**

`←[1;35merr: /Stage[main]/Php/File[/etc/php5/apache2/apc.ini]/ensure: change from
 absent to present failed: Could not set 'present on ensure: No such file or dir
ectory - /etc/php5/apache2/apc.ini.puppettmp_6187 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules
-0/php/manifests/init.pp:44←[0m`

`←[1;35merr: /Stage[main]/Php/File[/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini]/ensure: change from
 absent to present failed: Could not set 'present on ensure: No such file or dir
ectory - /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini.puppettmp_6687 at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules
-0/php/manifests/init.pp:36←[0m`

**/modules/php/manifests/init.pp**

```
file { "/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini":
  ensure => present,
  mode => 644,
  content => template("php/etc/php5/conf.d/php.ini.erb"),
  require => Package["php5"],
  notify => Service["apache"];
}

file { "/etc/php5/apache2/apc.ini":
  ensure => present,
  mode => 644,
  content => template("php/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini.erb"),
  require => [ Package["php5"], Package["php-apc"], Package["apache"] ],
  notify => Service["apache"];
}
```

**Templates**

- /modules/php/templates/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini.erb
- /modules/php/templates/etc/php5/conf.d/php.ini.erb

Comment: Doesn't warrant an answer, but make sure your virtualbox is up to date. That solved this for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure Package["php5"] it's creating the path for you?

It seems to me that it's complaining because /etc/php5/apache2 folder does not exist when it tries to create the files from the templates.

If you want to discard your puppetmaster side you can find puppetmaster process id and run:

```
strace -v -f -ff -p $PID -o strace.log
```

Then, run the agent again and go to puppetmaster and run:

```
grep "etc/php5/apache2" strace.log.*
```

If puppetmaster it's ok you will see the reading call without errors, else you will see that  puppetmaster receives "no such file or directory" when trying to open the file. Anyway as you I don't think the problem it's with template call, seems ok to me,.

Answer (score 12):

Just ensure that directory /etc/php5/apache2 exists.

```
file { [ "/etc", "/etc/php5", "/etc/php5/apache2" ]:
   ensure => directory,
   before => File['/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini'],
}
```

or little less Puppet-ish

```
exec { "ensure /etc/php5/apache2":
  command => "mkdir -p /etc/php5/apache2",
  creates => "/etc/php5/apache2"
}
```

All this is probably because of assumptions on the order of execution.

More info @ the [puppet docs](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/types/file.html#file-attribute-ensure)

Comment: For any puppet newcomers - the `before => File['...']` CANNOT have a space between `File` and the `[` character. You will get a syntax error.